# How can I remove the ends of this tap spout?

Tags: plumbing, taps

[image]

I'm trying to find a shower that fits these taps but with no success.I have seen showers with ends that screw into the tap spout but I don't know how to remove the black plastic ends that are already in there.

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want: are you looking for a [faucet aerator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faucet_aerator) for the end of this faucet?

Comment: Usually the end caps are just friction fit. You can pry them off with your fingernail or a small screwdriver.

Comment: Yes Daniel,as the taps have flat spouts I'm thinking the only way I can attach a shower to these taps is to remove the black plastic ones with ones that have a thread on so the shower hose can be screwed on

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post to add extra information, and `add a comment` to reply to someone who has commented on yours. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Comment: Yes Daniel,as the taps have flat spouts I'm thinking the only way I can attach a shower to these taps is to remove the black plastic ones with ones that have a thread  on so the shower hose can be screwed on that way.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I haven't seen separate hot & cold taps in a long time. I'd say it's time for an upgrade. It looks like you've been after that pictured one pretty good. I'd spray them inside & out with vinegar a half dozen times throughout an entire day & then run the hot water one for a minute.

The hot water would heat it up & hopefully loosen everything, including any mineral deposits that the vinegar broke-up. Then, give it another jerking twist, rather than a slow torqueing twist. If that all works on the hot side, then you'd pour hot water over the vinegar-ed cold tap until that's heated.

I can't make out if the black plastic piece is hollow or not. But, if it is I think your only other option is to use an Internal Pipe wrenching bit of the right diameter, [**like this.**](http://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-Internal-Pipe-Wrench-Set-HDX150/204218626)

Comment: Thanks Iggy I will try that.Im presuming they are hollow as water comes through them.Its not my house so upgrading or installing a shower with electrics and plumbing isn't an option I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I just meant the ends might be aerators & you'd have to bust those out in order for the Internal Pipe wrench bit to get a solid grip. But, hopefully the vinegar, heat & jerking does the trick.

Comment: Thanks Iggy that worked a treat,much obliged.Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: Fantastic! Good luck with the shower hook-up, it'll be a great improvement.

Comment: @Iggy separate taps for hot and cold are still quite common in many places in the world, especially in the UK. If I had to guess, that is where the OP is from.

Comment: I've actually never ever seen them on a tub, where they could actually make some sense. I lived horribly with them for a few years on a sink.